# Integrate vuforia in my own android app

Tags: java, android, vuforia

I have manage to follow all of [these](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-android-native-sdk) steps and able to compile and run the sample apps given by Vuforia in my real android device.

What i wanted to do is integrate 1 feature from Vuforia SDK to my own android app which is the Vuforia's Image Target feature. Is there any tutorial to guide me in integrating Image Target feature to my own app? I have searched the web intensively and haven't found any references or tutorials that will help you integrate or create your own android application using Vuforia SDK.

I am very lost on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [tutorial](http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Integrating_JPCT-AE_with_Vuforia) back in the day on how to integrate Vuforia with jPCT-AE.

Depending on what you want to achieve it might suit your needs or not. Whether  you want to use jPCT-AE or not, the concepts should be similar applied to any engine.

Of course you need a little knowledge on computer graphics and matrix algebra.